# PHPmailer cant connect with remote SMTP server

Tags: php, smtp, fedora, xampp

I cant connect with remote SMTP server using PHPmailer. I checked in wireshark, that in time when script is trying to connect, no single packet is sent out from my pc.

What can block it? SELinux is disabled, firewall too. Im using Fedora 14 wirh xampp 1.7.7

Comment: Can you connect to the SMTP server from telnet?

Comment: No, im getting 'No route to host' message, but, thunderbird sends and receive e-mails without problems.

Comment: What did you put into telnet and what are the settings in thunderbird?

Comment: `telnet w25.webd.pl`

smtp settings in tb are: server name: w25.webd.pl, port: 465, connection sec.: ssl/tls and username with password

Comment: `telnet w25.webd.pl 25` works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Many antiviruses block outbound traffic on port 25. If you don't even see the traffic leaving your machine, chances are this is the case.

Comment: I dont have any av.